# How to get windows user language list using the CMD shell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am unable to get the windows user language list using CMD line command.

I have used `get-winuserlanguagelist` in PowerShell but I need its equivalent *cmd* command. For I face a troubleshooting issue on some PCs which are restricted by PowerShell policy.

Hence on those restricted PCs, I only have the CMD shell to solve this issue of  being able to remove an extra language that user doesn't need.

Note: Also Region & Language settings are disabled according to policy permissions.

Comment: Of what restriction are you talking? Can you still open a PS and enter commands interactively? Or does PS not even open?

Answer (score 3):

The restriction only applies to the execution of scripts. It is not a real security measure, it's only there to prevent users from accidentally run PS scripts. Here are some of many ways to bypass the resrtiction without applying changes to the system:

1. Run PS from CMD and pass your command with the `-Command` parameter:

   ```
   powershell -Command "Get-WinUserLanguageList"
   ```

   You can pass multiple lines (aka a script) by separating the lines by `;`:

   ```
   powershell -Command "Get-WinUserLanguageList; Write-Host 'Hello World!'"
   ```
2. Run PS from CMD and pass your code to `stdin`:

   ```
   echo Get-WinUserLanguageList | powershell
   ```
3. Run PS from CMD, bypass the execution policy and execute a script file:

   ```
   powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\my_script.ps1
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If a computer is restricted from changing such things by policy, then its up to the admin of the network to run a PowerShell script at an elevated level to change such things.

Otherwise, allowing such changes means viruses could change the user experience for the worse.

The direction one should take is to create the PowerShell script, but one needs to run it  at an admin level of authority.